# Number of rendered lines for UILabel with fixed width and NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a UILabel whose text is set dynamically via `-setAttributedText:`
The NSAttributedString contains a variety of dynamic attributes, namely different fonts or styles for different ranges of characters here and there throughout. The width of the UILabel is constrained (via autolayout), the height is variable (numberOfLines=0).

What I need to determine is the number of lines of text which are rendered given the NSAttributedString and width constraint.

**Please note that I am not looking for the height of the label, I am looking for the number of rendered lines. Also note that I can't perform any computations based on font.lineHeight because the font varies throughout the NSAttributedString.**

For some background, what would like to do is set `label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter` for labels which have 1 line and `label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft` for labels which have 2 or more lines. I would do this for example in `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` after autolayout and the UILabel have done their business. Or perhaps there is an easier way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 15):

Here is Swift 3 version

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    func numberOfLines(with width: CGFloat) -> Int {

        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
        let frameSetterRef : CTFramesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(self as CFAttributedString)
        let frameRef: CTFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetterRef, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path.cgPath, nil)

        let linesNS: NSArray  = CTFrameGetLines(frameRef)

        guard let lines = linesNS as? [CTLine] else { return 0 }
        return lines.count
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Providing some sort of explanation will help others to understand.

Comment: Works fine. Thank you

Comment: Does not work in all cases. In some edge cases, the `lines` array will look different as to how the UILabel arranges the lines, leading to the UILabel display 5 lines, while `lines` array saying it only needs 3 lines.

Comment: @LordZsolt have you found a consistant way of doing it. I also have a problem with a wrong number of lines

Answer (score 0):

Technically this doesn't answer the question of how to learn the number of lines of rendered text but I did find a solution to my problem so I thought I'd post it anyway.

What I ended up doing was removing the width autolayout constraint on the label (actually the leading and trailing constraints to the superview) and added a center horizontally in container constraint to it. Then in `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` I set `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth=self.view.frame.size.width-margin`. The label's `textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft`.

This achieves the same effect of having the label centered if it is only one line and left justified if it is two or more.

Answer (score -4):

You can set your `UILabel` with `NSMutableAttributedString` like this:

```
UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,100)];
[contentLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[contentLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"hello I am a long sentence that should break over multiple lines"];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13] range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

contentLabel.attributedText = string;
```

Hope this helps...